# File upload request through JMeter proxy recording and load test fails

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, file-upload, aspx, load-testing

I have issues recording a file upload request using JMeter Proxy. The file could be selected with the browse option and on pressing the `SAVE` or `SUBMIT` button the page refreshes and goes to the initial state.

I'm working on a load test project on a **On-Premise SharePoint(v2013) Website** with the following conditions,

1. *Form-based authentication* - Login and session cookies are working
   correctly with JMeter.
2. Need to pass few dynamic variables like
   **__EVENTVALIDATION**, **__VIEWSTATE**, **__REQUESTDIGEST**, 
   **__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR** which needs to be extracted using a **RegEx 
   Extractor in JMeter** from every request and needs to be passed to 
   subsequent POST request as parameters.

As a workaround, I used **BlazeMeter Chrome Extension** to record the file upload requests and all the API calls could be recorded correctly. But has issues replaying it in JMeter. The file upload fails again even though all the requests pass.

1. All the file upload *POST* requests passes with a success response code 
   of **200** and gives the same HTML content as the response, while replaying it in JMeter, but the file never gets uploaded.

Please let me know if you need any more explanation regarding the requests.